# rank and choose rows within two categories

Tags: compare, rank

I would like to keep some rows that meet the following requirements in my table. The table are attached.
For the same ID:

1. If have several rows in different unique groups, keep all rows. such as ID 1203.
2. If have rows in the same group, choose the rows with lowest value to keep. such as: 1202    C    6
3. According to the rules 1 & 2, for ID 1201, keep rows 1201   A   4 & 1201
   B   9

need to go through all IDs in the table with the same rules.

Any suggestions to solve it with SAS?

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBVc2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your input dataset is ds:
Run the below

```
proc sort data=ds;
  by id group value;
quit;


data a;
set ds;
by id group value;
if first.group;
run;
```